# Facing an issue in Event grid while using authentication

Tags: azure, identity, azure-eventgrid

I have a webapp (on Azure) which is sending messages to a eVent grid topic (on Azure same subscription) using sasKey. I have to eliminate the saskey usage and use the inbuilt roles & permissions. The webapp should be the only source for the messages in the event grid topic.

[image: (on Az]

I have tried these 2 options , but it is not working.

Option 1:

```
 Uri endpoint = new Uri(topicEndpoint);
                EventGridPublisherClient client = new EventGridPublisherClient(endpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
 gridEvent = new EventGridEvent(
                            subject: eventType,
                            eventType: eventType,
                            dataVersion: "1.0",
                            data: new
                            {
                                Property1 = "Property1Value",
                                Property2 = "Property12Value"
                            }
                        );

                    var result = client.SendEventAsync(gridEvent);
                    returnResponse = result.Result.ToString();
```

Option 2:

```
       Uri endpoint = new Uri(topicEndpoint);
                    EventGridPublisherClient client = new EventGridPublisherClient(endpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential(
                     new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
                     {
                         ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId
                     }
                    ));
 gridEvent = new EventGridEvent(
                            subject: eventType,
                            eventType: eventType,
                            dataVersion: "1.0",
                            data: new
                            {
                                Property1 = "Property1Value",
                                Property2 = "Property12Value"
                            }
                        );

                    var result = client.SendEventAsync(gridEvent);
                    returnResponse = result.Result.ToString();
```

//client id is teh application Id from the below s/s
[image]

I keep getting error.

*GraphQL error: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot - EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot - WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload options are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot - ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint. - Visual Studio Token provider can't be accessed at D:\DWASFiles\Sites\sbx-job-web-int\LocalAppData.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json - Azure CLI not installed - Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed. - Azure Developer CLI could not be found.))*

edit:
Also adding the screenshot of the web - app
[image]

In both , I am not able to send messages to the topic, any suggestions if I am missing anything??

Comment: please your error in text

Comment: Please attach the code you used.

Comment: Have you enabled managed identity for your webapp/app service? In your screenshots you are referring to an Enterprise application. Not sure where you got that from. I tried using option 1 and it is working fine for me. If you can confirm that you have enabled managed identity and attach your full code that would help.

Comment: @AnupamChand  I have added the screenshot of the web-app as well . It has the managed identity turned on. Also added the code, it is failing at the Default Azure Credential

Comment: Have you tried giving the proper permissions to the managed identity that is ending with "-web-int"? Give this the Event grid sender role and then try option 1. I think you have registered an app and using that client id as the managed identity which is not correct.

Comment: @AnupamChand the Enterprise Application is the "topic-int" role which has been added. I have added the same to the topic-int & web-app

Comment: Please remove the Event grid sender role from the topic-int Enterprise application. Keep it only for the managed identity that is "-web-int". It is possible that having it for both is causing the system to not understand which credential to pick up, the user who logged in or the managed identity.

Comment: Thanks @AnupamChand it really helped me to resolve this issue

Comment: @AnupamChand , was having another query on related topic... I am using EventGridPublisherClient to publish messages, I was trying to avoid creation of the object everytime... instead was trying to use DI

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @AnupamChand it really helped me to resolve this issue. As soon as I gave access to web-app , the issue was resolved